# How to download specific files from ftp?

Tags: ftp, wget

I wonder about how to download files, not all into index of directory.

For example, my question is how to download specific [files](ftp://cddis.nasa.gov/gnss/products/troposphere/zpd/),  which its name start "mat1", from 2015 to 2018 or index of 2018, between 001 and 067.

```
wget -r -nd -A 'mat1*' ftp://cddis.nasa.gov/gnss/products/troposphere/zpd/{2015...2018}.gz
```

or how to download mat1 files between 001 and 067 from 2015 index of directory?

I didn't know `ftp` code. As a first impression

```
ftp cddis.nasa.gov
Name (ftp.cddis.nasa.gov): anonymous
password:
ftp> cd gnssproducts/troposhere/zpd/
(Error: 550 Failed to change directory.)
prompt off
ftp> mget mat1*
```

Comment: Why not use the `ftp` command?